# how to show right-to-left language in FBReaderJ in android?

Tags: java, android, epub, epub3, epublib

I want to use FBReaderJ for reading Persian book that is an rtl language.
In FBReaderJ all words are shown correctly but words are reversed like this:

سلام بر شما  (correct)

شما بر سلام  (wrong) in FBReaderJ

I downloaded FBReaderJ source to see if I can do any thing to fix this problem but FBReaderJ is a huge project and I can not do it.

I found an edited version of FBReaderJ for supporting Arabic but I failed to import it or recognize what they did.

Do you have any idea ?

(sorry for bad english)

Comment: is there any special reason that you should use this app?... there are other apps and libraries that could do the same or even better (Most of Persian eBooks are in PDF which this app doesn't support).

Comment: i need only epub for some reason, i need an app to be open source , if you know any open source epub reader or any api for android please tell me

Comment: I haven't used any of these myself there should be some of good choices :https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=epub+android ... By the way what was your problem with Arabic version of this app?

Comment: it say: can not load native library.

Comment: how am i supposed to add native library?, in its orginal version i extracted native library from its apk and copy in libs folder in eclipse and it work, but in Arabic version NOT.  Can you help?